# How to get scroll down for 2 images (left and right) at a time?

Tags: css, scroll

I made two divs that when I scroll down ; images can move at the same time.

I used a `position:fixed` tag.

Now the 1st image is scrolling down, but the 2nd is not.

When I use `position:fixed` tag for the 2nd image div, then that becomes part of 1st image.

How can I resolve this issue?

I want when I scroll down both images should scroll down from left and right - towards down position.

Get results on my site: [Sagifill.com](http://sagifill.com)

Code:

```
<div style="width: 1300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"> 
<div style="float:left; padding:0px 5px 0px 5px; position:fixed;"> 
<a href="anrdoezrs.net/click-7588066-11740922"; target="_top"> 
<img src="lduhtrp.net/image-7588066-11740922"; width="160" height="600" alt="" border="0"/></a> 
</div>
<div style="float:right; padding:0px 5px 0px 5px; "> 
<a href="anrdoezrs.net/click-7588066-11740922"; target="_top"> 
<img src="lduhtrp.net/image-7588066-11740922"; width="160" height="600" alt="" border="0"/></a>      
</div> </div>
```

Comment: There's no way to scroll down on your website.

Comment: then tell me how to add scroll down. im here for solution don't tell me what is the problem tell me solution just.

Comment: Please post some code to make your question clearer

Comment: <div style="width: 1300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"> 

<div style="float:left; padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;  position:fixed;">
<a href="http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-7588066-11740922" target="_top">
<img src="http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-7588066-11740922" width="160" height="600" alt="" border="0"/></a>
</div>


<div style="float:right; padding:0px 5px 0px 5px; ">
<a href="http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-7588066-11740922" target="_top">
<img src="http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-7588066-11740922" width="160" height="600" alt="" border="0"/></a>
</div>
</div>

Comment: thanks to beatify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to float them with position:fixed. Try this:

```
<div style="padding:0px 5px; position:fixed; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <a href="anrdoezrs.net/click-7588066-11740922"; target="_top"> 
    <img src="lduhtrp.net/image-7588066-11740922"; width="160" height="600" alt="" border="0"/>
  </a>
</div>
<div style="padding:0px 5px; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;"> 
  <a href="anrdoezrs.net/click-7588066-11740922"; target="_top"> 
    <img src="lduhtrp.net/image-7588066-11740922"; width="160" height="600" alt="" border="0"/>
  </a>
</div>
```